# Get IP from DNS without using gethostbyname?

Tags: php, sockets, dns

PHP's [gethostbyname()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) function doesn't seem to be configurable as far as timeouts are concerned. I want to limit DNS requests to 1 second or less as anymore shows a problem and should be ignored.

So, is there a way to make a DNS query using sockets or cURL instead? I was able to make SMTP requests using PHP streams which saved server resources, so I'm looking to do the same with DNS queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments on the [PHP article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) have some options for setting/including a timeout:

```
<?php
function getAddrByHost($host, $timeout = 3) {
   $query = `nslookup -timeout=$timeout -retry=1 $host`;
   if(preg_match('/\nAddress: (.*)\n/', $query, $matches))
      return trim($matches[1]);
   return $host;
}
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php#92870

Comment: @Xeoncross: This is probably your best bet. Otherwise you can look at section `4.2` of the RFC ( http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1035.html ) and find out how to send your own packet.

Comment: Note that the [backtick `](http://php.net/operators.execution) is shorthand for [shell_exec()](http://php.net/shell-exec)