# PHP Parse Host+IP to IP Address only

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get this: `46-121-31-23.example.net`

To be parsed to this: `46.121.31.23`

Replacing the hyphens and removing the characters using REGEX wouldn't be enough, since the result of this would be `46.121.31.23..`

Comment: get everything up until the `.` then replace `-` with `.`

Comment: Not every provier gives you the host in that form. Your best chance to get the IP address is using `gethostbyname($yourHost)`

Comment: This is not HOST+IP, it's just HOST. Your question is not really precise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `gethostbyname()`? While your particular hostname has the IPv4 address encoded into its 'friendly' name, there's no guarantee that will always be true. So use the real name->ip lookup system: DNS

```
$ip = gethostbyname('46-121-31-23.example.net');
echo $ip; // 46.121.31.23
```

---

comment followup: That hostname obviously doesn't exist:

```
marc@panic:~$ host -t ns static.012.net.il             
static.012.net.il name server pdns.goldenlines.net.il.
static.012.net.il name server sdns.goldenlines.net.il.

marc@panic:~$ host 46-121-31-23.static.012.net.il pdns.goldenlines.net.il   
Using domain server:
Name: pdns.goldenlines.net.il
Address: 212.117.129.3#53
Aliases: 

Host 46-121-31-23.static.012.net.il not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

hence there's no way to do a DNS lookup, since the servers which are authoritative for that domain have no idea what you're talking about.

However, the reverse mapping (IP->Hostname) **DOES** work:

```
marc@panic:~$ host 46.121.31.23
23.31.121.46.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer 46-121-31-23.static.012.net.il.
```

So for some reason, that provider's only doing reverse mappings, and not forward.

Comment: Doesn't work for `gethostbyname('46-121-31-23.static.012.net.il')` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$ip = preg_replace("/\..*/", "", $ip);
$ip = str_replace("-", ".", $ip);
```

Though, I agree with @klaustopher that using `gethostbyname` is generally safer: (http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php).

**EDIT:**

Also, you could try doing it this way: [Get IP from DNS without using gethostbyname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305604/get-ip-from-dns-without-using-gethostbyname)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('/(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})/', $hostname, $ip)) {
    $ip = "{$ip[1]}.{$ip[2]}.{$ip[3]}.{$ip[4]}";
}
```

Should work.